# Using ancestry gem, how do I allow 1 node to have 2 parents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ancestry

Each parent can already have more than 1 children. How do I allow the reverse, i.e. 1 child to 2 parents?

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. `Ancestry` models tree hierarchies - that's one parent per child node.

Comment: Hrmm....you mean it models one type of tree hierarchy. A family tree, which is one type of tree hierarchy, violates that principle.

Comment: What would be a gem that could help me do this?

Comment: I meant tree as in a tree data structure - by definition, that allows one parent per child. What you need is most likely a graph - I don't know any gems for those, though, sorry.